# Add to user input value before storing in the database

Tags: php, sql

I have a form whereby a user fills it in and clicks submit. This then stores the information in the database. I have a field called height. And I want the user to type in something like 10, but I dont want them to type in the measurement aswel. I want this to be added to '10' before storing in the database

So when they click 10 and submit, i want it to show in the database as 10inches or 10".

I tried to google it but I get nothing because I have to be quite specific with keywords and I just dont know how to search it.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to store this in the database as text? That should not be a database concern, but instead be a UI concern. Store the 10, and just add the `inches` when you pull the data out?

Or you could store the 10 as a value alongside a mapping to what type it is (such as inches/cm/etc). This design will give you much more flexibility

Comment: Assuming there is only one unit of measure, this is probably the best approach. +1

Comment: @ImGreg I just updated my answer to cover multiple unit of measures actually.

Comment: Even better approach.  Good call.

Comment: Definitely number and Unit of Measure, a string would mean using the data for anything but 1 for one display would be a lot of code/sql.

Comment: Good Answer. Usually when the unit of measure can be different, you store the value in a NUMBER column, and a key or code representing the unit of measure in a column (I usually name it UOM).

Comment: sorry to sound dumb but what do you mean by mapping?

Comment: @user1278496 Basically, store the data as `10|1`   Where 1 is a foreign key to another table: `UnitOfMeasure` with columns `ID|TypeOfMeasure|DisplayText` and data like `1|Inches|"`

Comment: OK I understand now. But what if something was 10metres 2inches. In other words, what if a measurement is not exact?

Comment: @user1278496 First, I have never seen metric mixed with standard. Second, if you wanted 10 feet 2 inches, then you would store the value as 122 inches or 10.16667 feet

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to validate the textbox value on form submit (onSubmit)

In server php script, you could also check the value again.